# Getting the generic type parameter's class in Java

Tags: java, generics

I have a class that needs to handle objects which extend the `Number` class. To do this, I use a type parameter `T`. However, some of the functions in the class need to know what class `T` is (e.g. return an object of the same class as `T`).

The solution `Class<T> clazz = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getSuperClass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];` that pops up everywhere looks promising, since I could just use `isAssignableFrom`. However, the `getActualTypeArguments[0]` part returns a `TypeVariableImpl`, which obviously means that I need to do something different.

To be more specific, the code I currently have looks something like this:

```
public class Outer {
    //Sole purpose of the Dummy class is for the getGenericSupertype() method.
    private static abstract class Dummy<T> {
        private Class<T> clazz;

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public Dummy() {
            clazz = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) 
                    getClass().getGenericSuperclass())
                    .getActualTypeArguments()[0]; //ClassCastException
        }

        public Class<T> getClazz() {
            return clazz;
        }
    }

    public static class Foo<T extends Number> extends Dummy<T> {
        private Class<T> typeOfNumber;
        //...

        public Foo() {
            typeOfNumber = getClazz();
            //...
        }

        public Foo(T number) {
            this();
            //...
        }
        //...

        private boolean isA(Class<?> type) {
            return type.isAssignableFrom(typeOfNumber);
        }

        public T toThisType(double x) {
            if(isA(Integer.class))
                return new Integer((int) x);
            //...
        }
    }

    //Several functions that use Foo were omitted for brevity.
}
```

I intend to extend `Outer` in other classes and then create `Foo` objects for certain operations. If possible, I do not want to put something like `Class<T> clazz` in any of the constructors. In short, is there any way for an object declared `new Foo<Integer>()` to know that `T` is an `Integer`?

Comment: "is there any way for an object declared new Foo<Integer>() to know that T is an Integer?" type inference

Comment: No.  There is no way to make this work without passing the Class explicitly, except _possibly_ for making a new subclass at every location.  `new Foo<Integer>() {}` could potentially do it.  That said, trying to generically handle different kinds of Numbers is 99% of the time more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: Darn. I guess I'll have to either require a `Class<?>` variable in the constructor or see if Guava has a solution.

Comment: Or you could just make a function `public <T> T toType(double x, Class<T> type) {}` and then check `if(type. isAssignableFrom(Integer.class) return new Integer(x)` without even needing a pointless generic at class level.